# Doxygen - How to show all places where a class is used?

Tags: c++, doxygen, doxywizard

Can doxygen+graphviz generate a list or a graph of all usage of a class/struct/typedef/enum/etc.? It would be like a caller graph, but not for functions.

The ideal graph would be like a reversed collaboration diagram. It would have all classes that uses the class of interest have an edge pointing to the node of the class of interest.

A list of (all function that uses the class of interest) and/or (all classes that have a member of the class of interest) would also be nice.

Is there such a functionality in doxygen+graphviz yet? Thanks.

Comment: Does the collaboration view satisfy your requirements?  Try turning on UML view.

Comment: Unfortunately, turning on UML_LOOK does not change the collaboration diagram to what I was looking for. I was already generating the collaboration diagrams. The collaboration diagram shows all classes that a certain class uses/contains. I am looking for a diagram (or a list) of all classes that uses/contains a certain class. That's what I meant by a reversed collaboration diagram. Thanks for your response in any case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [doxygen manual](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/diagrams.html) for graphs and diagrams lists, which kind of graphs could be created. I wasn't able to find a graph, like the one you are looking for, in that list.

The manual also states:

`Warning: When you have a very large class hierarchy where many classes derive from a common base class, the resulting image may become too big to handle for some browsers.`

My feeling tells me that your intended functionality, for e.g. a class like String, would go beyond the scope of any usefull usage. However my feeling might be wrong, but I'm inclined to say it's impossible, at least yet.